# Scraping Wikipedia

Tags: python, web-scraping, wikipedia

I wish to scrape Wikipedia's table but I am facing difficulties.

1. On this website (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chemical_elements), I wish to import the entire list as dataframe.
2. On this website (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen), I wish to import the summary table data on the right hand side of the page.

What's the best way for me to do these? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will have to write some code.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find the answer to my first question. Thanks all.

```
summary_url = 
requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chemical_elements').text
summary_soup = bs(summary_url,'html')
summary_table = summary_soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable collapsible'})

array = []

rows = summary_table.findAll('tr')
header = [col.text for col in rows[1].findAll('th')]

for row in rows[2:-1]:
    tmp_row = []
    for column in row.findAll('td'):
        tmp_row.append(column.text)
    array.append(tmp_row)

df_raw = pd.DataFrame(array, columns=header)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with pandas like below

```
>>>import pandas as pd

>>>table = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chemical_elements')

>>>table[1]
```